# change color in FooterTab in React-native using native-base library

Tags: react-native, customization, native-base

Can't seem to customize the `FooterTab` properties.

In the documentation it doesn't say much about how to edit.

This is my code:

```
<FooterTab
  tabActiveBgColor="#4fb5f9"
  tabBarActiveTextColor="#2d83bc"
  tabBarTextColor="#6b6b6b">
  <Button>
    Inventory
    <Icon name="ios-list-box-outline" />
  </Button>
  <Button>
    Survey
    <Icon name="ios-camera-outline" />
  </Button>
</FooterTab>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check the Docs for [Customizing components](https://docs.nativebase.io/Customize.html#theaming-nb-headref)

[image]

Change the variables [here](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/master/src/theme/variables/commonColor.js#L119) for FooterTab

Comment: Please add the text of the code, not the image as suggested [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)